# Making a button easier to click

Tags: android, user-interface, button, interface, view

I have a button that on certain phones is too hard to click because of its size.

But making it bigger breaks layout.

It is possible to explain to a view that it has a bigger "click box" than its visible area?

Comment: Can you put up the XML and give us an idea on what devices/screen sizes it's broken on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure if this can help:

If you use an ImageButton with no background and you set a Padding value, your button will have a larger clickable area.

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/img_close" android:id="@+id/btnClose" 
    android:padding="25dip" android:background="#0000"></ImageButton>
```

Comment: I will test that later, probably it will break the layout (making a centered button in a huge area)

Comment: I used this successfully for a similar "button is too small" issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Propably the best thing would be to create a layout for each [density / screen size](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Like, create bazillions of layouts?

Comment: there are some screen sizes that you could support. for example hdpi, mdpi and ldpi. If your issues just pop up with one of these screen sizes, you just need to create a separate layout for devices with those screens.

Comment: there are some devices with the same theoretical screen size but that are harder to click than others.

Comment: If you [read this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) of the link I provided above, you'll see that this is a recommended practice for Android development.

Comment: What I am saying is that even using that technique, the thing is STILL broken on some phones, and putting a humongous button on them is not a option.

Comment: Hmmmm... could you provide us with screen shots of the working and the broken layout?

Comment: It is not the layout that is broken, it is the button that is too small. But making it bigger DO break the layout (any layout)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps in your particular case, but you can make a Linear/RelativeLayout take clicks ([setClickable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29)). So you may be able to enable clicks on the Button's parent and obtain your desired effect?