# Add bigger transparent overlay to increase clickable area, without changing layout

Tags: android, layout, overlay

I want to increase the clickable area of my button (ImageView). But I don't want this to be reflected visually. It has to look like the button is small (no margin, padding, etc.) but the clickable area is big.

[image]

The only thing I can think about is put my whole layout in a RelativeLayout and add the overlays programmatically to a second "layer". Calculate margin left and margin top with maths.

Is there a better approach?

I already looked here
[Expand clickable area of an ImageView by using padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107824/expand-clickable-area-of-an-imageview-by-using-padding)

or here
[Making a button easier to click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898314/making-a-button-easier-to-click)

And some others but they always change the layout adding padding or transparent areas to the image, I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `TouchDelegate`, as outlined in [this blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-change-touch-area-of-view-by-touchdelegate-fc19f2a34021).

The gist is that you can define a `TouchDelegate` object and attach it to a widget to increase its touch area, without having a visual impact.

In Kotlin, this might look like:

```
    fun setExpandedTouchArea(view: View, extraSpace: Int) {
        val parent = view.parent as View

        parent.doOnLayout {
            val area = Rect()

            view.getHitRect(area)

            area.top -= extraSpace
            area.bottom += extraSpace
            area.left -= extraSpace
            area.right += extraSpace

            parent.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(area, view)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is almost, but not exactly what I'm looking for. The difference is that the area is limited to the bounds of the parent view, and I'm looking for something which is not limited to it. But I'll use this, it's easy to implement and will improve the "touchability" of my views well enough. I guess otherwise I have to implement it programmatically and that's not worth it, in this case.

Comment: @CommonsWare That second link is invalid.