# Increase the hit size of a button with a drawable border background without increasing the size of the border

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

So i have a simple drawable that creates a border

```
<shape>
<stroke android:width="3dp" 
 android:color="orange" />
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>

<corners android:radius=".." />
<padding
    android:bottom=".."
    android:left=".."
    android:right=".."
    android:top=".." />
```

The padding I already have is for the space between the text and the border. That makes it look pixel perfect for me, my issue is that i want more space on the outside of this border. At the moment if i add padding to the button itself the background drawable just stretches to encapsulates the added padding which is not what i want.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="my_drawable"
    // Tried adding padding but the background border just stretches and adds the 
       more space between the border and the center text
    android:paddingTop=".."
    android:paddingBottom=".."
     />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11073104/115145

Comment: Did you get any solutions? Please share present/required image screenshots